# meta-analysis combining categorical and continuous measures of predictor variable

Tags: descriptive-statistics, meta-analysis, effect-size

I'm beginning a meta-analysis.  Our response variable is a continuous measure (a measure of colony efficiency), and the predictor variable is the number of individuals in a social insect colony.  In some species, the colonies are always small (1-4 individuals), but in others the sizes range in the 100s to 1000s.  For small-colony species, data are typically reported and analyzed with a categorical predictor (usually 1-individual colonies vs 2+ individual colonies), and thus amenable to calculating cohen's d or some similar effect size.  For large-colony species , we are obtaining correlation coefficients calculated from scatterplot data, and plan to use r as our effect size.

In this situation, does it make sense to conduct two separate analyses, one for each type of predictor, categorical and continuous?  Or would it be better to find a way to convert one effect size into the other to allow a single analysis (probably using r).  Our question ("Within a species, does increasing colony size result in decreasing efficiency?") applies to both types of data, but I can't decide if somehow converting our standardized mean differences (d) into something like r to allow a single analysis makes sense or would be at all valid.

I'm obviously new to this stuff, and very grateful for any advice you can give!